# RxJS unsubscription with setInterval

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I call the unsubscribe method from that example ?

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.create(function subscribe(observer) {
 // Keep track of the interval resource
  var intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    observer.next('hi');
  }, 1000);

  // Provide a way of canceling and disposing the interval resource
  return function unsubscribe() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  };
});
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you have now?

Comment: I want to perform a unsubscription

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like this

```
let subscription = observable.subscribe(sub=> {
    // call unsubscribe
    subscription.unsubscribe();
});
```